# How to Call a PHP Function that is in an Array using Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I couldn't find anything that answers my question so here it is:

I need to have a foreach loop to take each function inside of an array and run each and check if it returns true, simple enough. Like this:

```
$array_name = array(function1(),function2(),function3());

foreach($array_name as &$value) {
    /* run each function */
    /* checks if it returns true */
}
```

This may be so easy I just don't see it, but I can't find any definitive documentation on how to correctly implement this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array_name = array('function1', 'function2', 'function3');

foreach($array_name as $value) {
    if($value()) {
        // do stuff if the function returned a true-ish value
    }
}
```

Another option to call the function would be [`call_user_func($value)`](http://php.net/call_user_func).

Comment: `if ($value())` should be `if (function_exists())`.

Comment: He wants to call the function, not check if it exists. In that case it would be `function_exists` or `is_callable`.

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
$array_name = array('function1','function2','function3');

foreach($array_name as &$value) {
  if(function_exists($value) && ($value())) {
     //function exists and it returns true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adopt things from : http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

```
foreach($functionName as $arg) {
    $arg();
}
```

But as you question contains:

> $array_name = array(function1(),function2(),function3());

Make sure "function1()" is used in your array. So we can have:

```
foreach($functionName as $arg) {
   $check = $arg;
   if($check != false){
     //Do stuff here
   }else{
     //Do stuff here
   }
}
```